# Optimize python's string.format

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.5, string.format

I have a web service that is running on Python 3.5 which serves some trace messages to users. The trace messages are stored in a decoder as python string format. Every trace stores an ID and parameters list. When a user tries to fetch the traces I loop through the traces and format them using the trace message format.

For example:

```
def message(self, parameters=[]):
    if len(parameters) == 0:
        return self._message
    return  self._message.format(*parameters)
```

Referring to the above code, the format function is extremely slow in python. I have used cProfile to profile my code and squeezed every ms I can get but the bottleneck is the `string.format()`, since I have to format many messages. It takes seconds to serve just a small sample of what is supposed to be served.

So my question is, is there anyway to speed this up, giving the fact that I have only few list of string formats? I mean it is inefficient to parse the same format string 1000000 times and then do the variable replacement. Can I implement some sort of caching using string.Formatter class for example?

Just a note the traces are stored and loaded in `string.format()` format, so using `%` replacement format is not a direct option, even though it saves at least half the time using that format and it saves even more as the number of parameters increase.

What makes things worse is that `string.format()` takes linear time with the number of parameters!

The trace messages usually contains some strings with some parameters that needs to be replaced by decimal or hexadecimal numbers like the following:

```
"Some text followed by variable {:0d} , Other variable 0x{:08X}"
```

I have also looked into [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) and it looks like the string format is inefficient because it parses the string over and over whenever format is called with the same string. I wonder if there is a way to optimize a formatter so that it caches the string format and avoid all the parsing if it is done before?

Comment: Depending on how your `self._message` looks like there are ways to improve it. However without knowing `self._message` it's tricky to recommend improvements because they may or may not be appropriate.

Comment: You could try using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) and `printf`. No idea if it would be faster or slower.

Comment: Can you preformat the variables and then just concatenate the strings as in `"Some text followed by variable " + preformated1 + ", Other variable 0x" + preformated2`? That way you don't need to parse anything. Does performance improve if you replace preformatedN with `"{:nx}".format(N)`? Admittedly, this requires some refactoring but it might be wort it.